# Define heap key for an array of tuples

Tags: python, heap

A simple example for the usage of the [python heap implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) is

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop
heap = []
data = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0]
for item in data:
    heappush(heap, item)
```

In a more complicated scenario, I have an array of tuples like

```
tuples = [(5,"foo",True),(2,"bar", False),(8,"foobar",True)]
```

and want to use the first entry of each tuple as heap key, i.e. the tuples should be sorted according to the number in the tuples.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a way to do the same if my key was the **second or third** element of the tuple?
Also, what if I wanted the **reverse order** for *heapify* ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply use the tuple as they are. The [Python documentation explicitly makes note](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html#basic-examples) of such as usage:

> Heap elements can be tuples. This is useful for assigning comparison values (such as task priorities) alongside the main record being tracked:
>
> ```
> >>> h = []
> >>> heappush(h, (5, 'write code'))
> >>> heappush(h, (7, 'release product'))
> >>> heappush(h, (1, 'write spec'))
> >>> heappush(h, (3, 'create tests'))
> >>> heappop(h)
> (1, 'write spec')
> ```

Simply push the tuples to the heap, and pop them off when needed:

```
>>> from heapq import heappush, heappop
>>> 
>>> heap = []
>>> tuples = [(5,"foo",True),(2,"bar", False),(8,"foobar",True)] 
>>> 
>>> for tup in tuples:
...     heappush(heap, tup)
... 
>>> heappop(heap)
(2, 'bar', False)
```

Because [the implementation for `heap`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/heapq.py#L212) uses default sorting for tuples

```
while pos > startpos:
    ...
    if newitem < parent:
        ...
    ...
...
```

and Python sorts tuples element-wise, ensure the objects by which you want the tuples to be sorted come first.

Comment: And if I want to sort by the second element in the tuples? How can I do that?

Comment: You could create a [custom tuple class](https://repl.it/repls/GenuineSoreBackticks#main.py) which is sorted by its second element. But the simpler solution to me, if possible, would be to just flip the position of the first and second elements, so no special classes are needed. Something like `flipped_tuples = [(tup[1], tup[0], tup[2])] for tup in tuples]`.